# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method Generic.List(int) to Generic.IEnumerable(int) method

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-4.0, linq-to-entities

The database contains Orders.
Orders can be contained within a group of Orders.
For every group of Orders it could contain 1 to many Orders.

However, Orders could have a NULL value assigned GroupOrderId as previous Orders did not have the grouping concept. Only new Orders enforce the concept of being added to a group.

The class structure to be populated in order to perform actions on each Order is

```
public class OrdersGroup
{
    public int? GroupOrderId { get; set; }
    public List<int> OrderIds { get; set; }
}
```

The linq statement

```
var workPacketOrdersList = (from o in db.Orders
                                    where
                                        o.GroupOrderId >= groupOrderIdMin && o.GroupOrderId <= groupOrderIdMax &&
                                        o.IsDeleted == false
                                    orderby o.WorkPacketId ascending
                                    group o by o.WorkPacketId
                                    into grp
                                    select new OrdersGroup
                                               {
                                                   GroupOrderId = grp.Key,
                                                   OrderIds = grp.Select(g => g.OrderId).ToList()
                                               }).ToList();
```

Full exception

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32] ToList[Int32](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Int32])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

I see that the returned type of the linq query is a `List<OrdersGroup>`.

If the final .ToList() is omitted from the query than the return type becomes an `IQueryable<OrdersGroup>`

No matter what action is performed next the result is an exception that this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

I have tried to remove the specific `select new OrdersGroup` into a more generic `select new` and then perform actions on this result only to find the same store expression exception.

Can someone give some insight into where this linq is incorrect?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

this is the part that's failing - `grp.Select(g => g.OrderId).ToList()` - you can't have a .ToList() in the select clause. remove that and you should be fine.

Comment: If I could mark all 4 answers correct I would. This was first.

Comment: should you change (public List<int> OrderIds { get; set; }) to (public IEnumerable<int> OrderIds { get; set; }) ??

Comment: @SaraN no, since List<> implements the IEnumerable<> interface, it wouldn't solve anything.

Comment: Yes! because the projected result is not strictly guaranteed to _be_ `List<>`

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that LINQ to Entities is attempting to convert your query into SQL. It doesn't know how translate `ToList` into SQL, so that's the problem. You need to remove the call to `ToList` from inside your query.

That is,

```
OrderIds = grp.Select(g => g.OrderId).ToList()
```

LINQ to Entities can not convert that to SQL. Remove the call

```
OrderIds = grp.Select(g => g.OrderId)
```

and if you need `OrderIds` to be a `List<int>`, do the call to `ToList` after you execute the query.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you're trying to call `ToList()` in a part of the query that will become raw SQL and executed at the source (ie SQL Server, not the CLR). I don't know exactly what your data is so I can't necessarily make an accurate recommendation on how to fix it but I would try taking making the `ToList()` call after this query or just not making it all. It's likely `IEnumberable` will offer whatever functionality you need which is what the `Select` will return if you remove the `ToList()` call.

By the way since I wasn't explicit, I'm referring to the `ToList()` call inside the select -(second to last line) `OrderIds = grp.Select(g => g.OrderId).ToList()` the other one is fine. It's executed on the results of the SQL query which is perfectly fine, you just can't make calls to C# specific methods within a query that will be executed by the SQL provider.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the clarification that the inner .ToList() was the c# specific call

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you select a list in your select statement.

```
select new OrdersGroup
{
   GroupOrderId = grp.Key,
   OrderIds = grp.Select(g => g.OrderId).ToList()
   /////////////////////////////////////^^^^^^^^^HERE
}
```

What you need to do is change `OrderIds` to an `IEnumerable<int>`, and then get rid of the `ToList`.

Comment: In 2020, this is still the least code, most performant solution.