# How to get a list of elements which are available in list and model class?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to get list of objects which has same id values in getAvailableList() method. Below is what I have done up to now:

```
public ActionResult Ataxi()
{
    var alist = IM.getAvailableList().Select(x => new sub_employee { SE_ID = x }).ToList();
    return View(alist);
}
```

The code above returns id values passed by getAvailableList() method. I want to find a `sub_employee` list, which have equal `SE_ID` values to values in get from `getAvaialableList()` method. I can't find a way to get the list of `sub_employee`s who has equal ids to list of int values passed by `getAvailableList()` method. How to solve this problem?

Comment: [This](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/advice-for-non-native-english-speakers) is for you.

Answer (score 0):

I do not fully understand your question. Do you have an Employee list (employees) from where you are trying to get the list of sub_employees having IDs in getAvailableList().

Consider employees is the list of class sub_employee.

```
//This is just an example. Please substitute your list variable name that you fetch from database for sub_employee
var employees = new List<sub_employee>();
```

If this is the case, then you can write it like:

```
var alist = employees.Where(e => IM.getAvailableList().ToList().Contains(e.Id));
```

Comment: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32[] getAvailableList()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression. I got this error

Comment: Do you have a list of sub_employee objects and you are trying to intersect 2 lists then you can use .Intersect method: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb910215(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: What kind of object is IM and is there any method/extension method called getAvailableList()?

Comment: IM is WSDL web service which contains method getAvailableList()

Comment: I assume then IM.getAvailableList() returns a list of int. And i still cannot understand if you have any employee list?

Comment: yes.IM.getAvailableList() returns int[] . I have List of sub_emmployees in my database.

Comment: I have edited my answer based on your responses. Does that work?

Comment: I have try it.I got error message Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32] ToList[Int32](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Int32])' method, and this

Comment: do you have this using statement in your .cs file 
using System.Linq;

Comment: Also check out this link if this is similar to your issue for the Select clause http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18086005/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-generic-listint-to-generic-ienu

Comment: I think your problem is IM.getAvailableList(). First get this in a variable   var list = IM.getAvailableList() and see what you get.

Comment: it contains list of integers

Comment: `public ActionResult Ataxi()
        {
            var alist = IM.getAvailableList().ToList();
            foreach(var item in alist)
            {
                var Alist = db.sub_employee.Where(s => s.SE_ID == item).ToList();
                
            }
            return View(Alist);
            
        }`

Comment: I want to return Alist.but it shows error in Action method name Ataxi

Comment: Instead of foreach, write it this way: 
        public ActionResult Ataxi()
        {
            var alist = IM.getAvailableList().ToList(); 
            var Alist = db.sub_employee.Where(s => alist.Contains(s.SE_ID)).ToList();
            return Json(Alist);
        }
Do you want to return View or Json data. For View, you need declare model in your view.

Comment: public ActionResult Ataxi()
        {
            List<sub_employee> AList = new List<sub_employee>();
            var alist = IM.getAvailableList().ToList();
            foreach(var item in alist)
            {
                AList = db.sub_employee.Where(s => s.SE_ID == item).ToList();
                
            }
            return View(AList);
            
        }

Comment: above is return last item in way what I want. How do I get All list items from it?

Comment: See my previous comment. return Json(Alist);

Comment: I have tried your method.but it returns ''This request has been blocked because sensitive information could be disclosed to third party web sites when this is used in a GET request. To allow GET requests, set JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet. ''

Comment: return Json(Alist, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);